# Bash add array string suffix to an array

Tags: bash, loops

I have two bash arrays, and I want to append array strings to the end of the name array elements.

```
array=(a b c)
name=(toto_ tata_)
```

result :

```
toto_a
toto_b
toto_c
tata_a
tata_b
tata_c
```

I tried those command :

```
for i in "${name[@]}"
do
    arra=( "${i/%/$array[@]}" )
done
printf '%s\n' "${arra[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a second `for`:

```sh
array=(a b c)
name=(toto_ tata_)
arra=()

for i in "${name[@]}"; do
    for j in "${array[@]}"; do
        arra+=("$i$j")
    done
done
printf '%s\n' "${arra[@]}"
```

Will produce:

```
toto_a
toto_b
toto_c
tata_a
tata_b
tata_c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEETP2a9YQqQJfoIE/A8tZWtbTMFdSfci4rdHExTnMId5MzPSdi2FcqZH9IQjXgIw3eboVVQGVFIaAtRC9AFgkYwJE6N1z9o7HfuXPeAkYCpav6gd/hl@ZEwN99Fbl9xqA5hJeIZm95xYF@x225m7377NS3kD)

Comment: This could by done [without `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70214902/1765658)!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) to expand as a cross-product

```sh
readarray -t new_array < <(IFS=,; eval "printf '%s\n' {${name[*]}}{${array[*]}}")
# ....................................................^..........^^...........^
```

then

```sh
$ declare -p new_array
declare -a new_array=([0]="toto_a" [1]="toto_b" [2]="toto_c" [3]="tata_a" [4]="tata_b" [5]="tata_c")
```

Eval is necessary to allow the variable expansion to occur first, then perform the brace expansion second.

Comment: Or  just: `(IFS=,; eval "printf '%s\n' {${name[*]}}{${array[*]}}")`... Nice, but not easy to debug! I don't like to play with `$IFS`... but here, it's fun ;-)

Comment: Or even, moving `eval` at begin of line: `. <(IFS=,;echo $'printf "%s\\n"' "{${name[*]}}{${array[*]}}")`

Comment: Nice but this will fail to work properly if an array element contains a `,`. Also it must be noted that array elements will be subject to `eval` too (Assume `name=(toto_ tata_ '$(some_command)')`, then `some_command` will be executed by `eval`!). So array elements must be sanitized if they come from an external source.

Answer (score 1):

### Second `for` could be avoided by *Parameter expansion*

```
for nam in "${name[@]}";do printf "${nam/%/%s\\n}" "${array[@]}";done
```

will produce:

```
toto_a
toto_b
toto_c
tata_a
tata_b
tata_c
```

#### For fun, some variants (without *any* `for` loop):

```
printf -v fmt "${name[*]/%/%%s\\n}"
printf "${fmt// }" ${array[@]}
toto_a
tata_b
toto_c
tata_
```

or

```
printf -v fmt "${name[*]/%/%%s\\n}";printf "${fmt// }" ${array[@]}{,}
toto_a
tata_b
toto_c
tata_a
toto_b
tata_c
```

then without `for`, but with a *fork* to `sort`

```
printf -v fmt "${name[*]/%/%%s\\n}";printf "${fmt// }" ${array[@]}{,} |
    sort -k 1r,1.5
toto_a
toto_b
toto_c
tata_a
tata_b
tata_c
```